# Xcode embedded binaries release vs. debug

Tags: ios, xcode

We have been provided two frameworks from another team for inclusion in our iOS app. A Debug version that contains simulator and device symbols and the Release version that contains only device symbols. They asked us to include the framework as an embedded binary.

How do we conditionally include an embedded binary the way we specify release and debug paths for frameworks in Build Settings? We do not want to manually intervene when it is time to build for the App Store and we want to include the release version of the library.

Comment: I created two folders, debug and release, and put the proper framework bundle in the right folder. Then in the target setting set the `framework search path` to point to those folders.

Comment: @DavidSkrundz how did that work for you? setting up folders and `frameworks search paths` works for me as well but I still have to embed the framework in the target and have to decide which one of the two I want to include. I don't see an option to switch the file based on release/ debug

Comment: @benrudhart are you find solution to this, please let me know if there is a solution

Comment: @SoftwareDeveloper unfortunately I don't know anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to create a new Target and remove the embedded binary.  Then in your code use compiler directives to conditionally include the headers/code.

I don't think it's ideal, but got me working!